# Isotope side borders

Tags: html, css, jquery-isotope

I'm using a plugin with the isotope filter library, I have set the width to 33.33% so my list elements with be divided into 3 columns. I want to select the middle one to set side borders, but when I click the filter, the element will be moving by position left. This means my original CSS, `:nth-child(3n+2)` will not be correct anymore. Any advice on how I can always select the middle item because the `HTML` stays the same?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this a lot when I first started using Isotope with Masonry layouts, so I absolutely sympathize with you on this!

Turns out, in an Isotope/Masonry layout, the vertical spacing between grid items is called **gutter**, and you don't need to use left/right margins at all.

Here's an example:

Let's say you have a grid of nine items, and you want it to be three columns, with a 2% gap in between each item. A great way to do this is to set up some "reference elements" in our HTML, which will act as templates for our grid item size and for our gutter size. Stay with me here. The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="grid">

    <div class="item-sizer"></div>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>

    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>

</div>
```

What we will then do, is target those first two "sizer" elements in our CSS, and set some widths. Eventually the Javascript will read this when we initialize Isotope. Here's the CSS:

```
.item-sizer {
    width: 32%;
}

.gutter-sizer {
    width: 2%;
}

/* note that this is the same as the .item-sizer */
.grid-item {
    width: 32%;
}
```

The `.item-sizer` acts as a template for how wide **columns** should be in our layout. The `.gutter-sizer` acts as a template for how wide **gutters** should be.

Some math to figure those numbers out:

In a 3-column layout, you're going to have two vertical gaps. Each of these gaps will be 2% (because that's how wide we decided we want our gaps to be), so 2% * 2 gaps = 4% total space occupied by gaps. If you take the full width of the grid (100%), and subtract our total gap space (4%), you're left with 96% to distribute evenly to your grid items. 96% / 3 columns is 32% each!

You'll then have to tweak your Isotope call to refer to those CSS selectors to size the grid and gutters accordingly:

```
$('#grid').isotope({

    // set itemSelector so .item-sizer and .gutter-sizer are not mistaken for grid items:
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    percentPosition: true,
    masonry: {
        // tell the layout to use the items we set up as sizing templates:
        columnWidth: '.item-sizer',
        gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
    }

});
```